# 1064 mysql error with creating a procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''v_id' varchar(20) null , OUT 'v_status' varchar(40)) IS Begin ' at line 2

It is the first time I'm using MySql and the little pl sql knowledge isn't really helping.

```
delimiter //
->CREATE PROCEDURE dbi292801.campsite
(IN 'v_id' varchar(20) null ,
               OUT 'v_status' varchar(40)) IS
 Begin 
               SELECT status into v_status FROM participant WHERE RFID = v_id;
              if (v_status = "in", v_status := "at campsite", v_status := 'at event');
            End if;
            End //
```

If you have an idea to solve this, please reply!!

Comment: Is the `->` intended, or a copy/paste artifact from  your client?

Comment: See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) -- variables, like column identifiers should be unquoted or quoted with backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: So `v_id, v_status` rather than `'v_id', 'v_status'`, but there may be other syntax problems I am not seeing (the `IS` keyword?)

Comment: [This is the MySQL CREATE PROCEDURE syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: oh sorry the -> is copy past error!

Comment: i deleted the single quotes thanks, but the error remains

Comment: Exact same error or different?